# Golang remap interface go-cache

Tags: go

I've got a struct like below:

```
type Page struct {
    title string
    url   string
}
```

and a map of structs:

```
 var mostViewed = make(map[int]Page)
```

With go-cache, I store the map with a TTL time.

```
c.Set("data", mostViewed, 60*time.Minute)
```

But, once I recover "data" key, how could I assing it back to a map?

```
a, _ := c.Get("data")
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a)

out: map[17:{title:xxx, url:yyy}]
```

I tried something like:

```
 z := map[int]Page{a}
```

Any clue? It's like "remapping" a mapped string.

Comment: With the question as-is, I have no idea what you are trying to do. Your variable `a` is of type `map[int]Page` which you cannot insert into a `map[int]Page` with your line `z := map[int]Page{a}`

Comment: Oh wait, I think I see what is going on. You are getting an `interface{}` type back. I'll answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an `interface{}` type back, but you know what it is, so you need to use a type assertion to cast it back to a `map[int]Page`. Here is a quick external resource. https://newfivefour.com/golang-interface-type-assertions-switch.html

Here is an example

https://play.golang.org/p/lGseg88K1m

```
type Page struct {
    title string
    url   string
}

func main() {
    m := make(map[int]Page)
    m[1] = Page{"hi", "there"}
    iface := makeIface(m)

    // use type assertion to cast it back to a map
    if mapAgain, ok := iface.(map[int]Page); ok {
        // it really is a map[int]Page
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", mapAgain)
    } else {
        // its not actually a map[int]Page
        fmt.Println("oops")
    }

    // alternatively use a type-switch if it could be multiple types
    switch v := iface.(type) {
        case map[int]Page:
            //yay
            fmt.Printf("%+v\n", v)
        case string:
            // its a string
            fmt.Println(v)
        default:
            // something we didn't account for

    }

}

func makeIface(m map[int]Page) interface{} {
    return m
}
```

Edit: as a side note, you probably want to make your map type `map[int]*Page` because if you did something like this:

```
page := m[1]
page.url = "different"
fmt.Println(page) // prints url="different"
fmt.Println(m[1].url) // remains unchanged
```

Because `page` would be a copy of what is in the map, not the `Page` in the map itself.